# APCS Gridworld - AnnoyingCritter null pointer

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, gridworld

Currently in AP Computer Science we're working on the gridworld case study, specifically a lab called AnnoyingCritter.  The requirements are such:

> Extend the Critter class to make a new AnnoyingCritter.  AnnoyingCritter will pick an actor at random to be its best friend forever (bFF) – the actor chosen must be an actor that will move.  AnnoyingCritter will follow / move towards its bFF in hopes of being near its bFF – it LOVES its BFF!  AnnoyingCritter will eat ONLY rocks and flowers as it does not like to eat things that can move.  AnnoyingCritter will always move one cell in the direction of its bFF.  If AnnoyingCritter cannot move to the cell in the direction of its BFF, it will move to any of its empty adjacent cells just like a normal critter.

The following code is what I've *attempted* to complete this.

```
import info.gridworld.actor.Actor;  
import info.gridworld.actor.Rock;
import info.gridworld.actor.Flower;
import info.gridworld.actor.Critter;
import info.gridworld.grid.Location;
import info.gridworld.grid.Grid;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.util.Random;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class AnnoyingCritter extends Critter
{
Random gen = new Random();
Grid<Actor> world = getGrid();
Actor bFF = pickFriend();

public Actor pickFriend() {
    ArrayList<Location> locs = world.getOccupiedLocations();
    int pick = gen.nextInt(locs.size());
    Actor temp = world.get(locs.get(pick));
    while(temp instanceof Rock || temp instanceof Flower) {
        pick = gen.nextInt(locs.size());
        temp = world.get(locs.get(pick));
    }
    return temp;
}
public void figureDirection() {
    int bFFCol = bFF.getLocation().getCol();
    int bFFRow = bFF.getLocation().getRow();
    int annoyCol = getLocation().getRow();
    int annoyRow = getLocation().getCol();
    Location next = null;
    if(bFFCol > annoyCol) {
        next = new Location(annoyRow, annoyCol+1);
    } else if(bFFCol < annoyCol) {
        next = new Location(annoyRow, annoyCol-1);
    } else if(bFFCol == annoyCol) {
        if(bFFRow > annoyRow) {
            next = new Location(annoyRow+1, annoyCol);
        } else if(bFFRow < annoyRow) {
            next = new Location(annoyRow-1, annoyCol);
        }
    }
    if(next != bFF.getLocation() || world.get(next) instanceof Rock) {
        world.get(next).removeSelfFromGrid();
        moveTo(next);
    } else {
        super.makeMove(super.selectMoveLocation(super.getMoveLocations()));
    }
}
public void act() {
    figureDirection();
}
}
```

The problem occurs on line 25 "ArrayList locs = world.getOccupiedLocations();" where I get a null pointer exception, presumably from the world.getOccupiedLocations().  Through experimentation I've determined that the world itself is null, though I don't understand why.  If more context is needed:

The critter class being extended:

```
package info.gridworld.actor;

import info.gridworld.grid.Location;

import java.util.ArrayList;

 public class Critter extends Actor
 {

public void act()
{
    if (getGrid() == null)
        return;
    ArrayList<Actor> actors = getActors();
    processActors(actors);
    ArrayList<Location> moveLocs = getMoveLocations();
    Location loc = selectMoveLocation(moveLocs);
    makeMove(loc);
}
public ArrayList<Actor> getActors()
{
    return getGrid().getNeighbors(getLocation());
}
public void processActors(ArrayList<Actor> actors)
{
    for (Actor a : actors)
    {
        if (!(a instanceof Rock) && !(a instanceof Critter))
            a.removeSelfFromGrid();
    }
}
public ArrayList<Location> getMoveLocations()
{
    return getGrid().getEmptyAdjacentLocations(getLocation());
}
public Location selectMoveLocation(ArrayList<Location> locs)
{
    int n = locs.size();
    if (n == 0)
        return getLocation();
    int r = (int) (Math.random() * n);
    return locs.get(r);
}
public void makeMove(Location loc)
{
    if (loc == null)
        removeSelfFromGrid();
    else
        moveTo(loc);
}
}
```

Finally the runner class:

```
import java.awt.Color; 
import info.gridworld.actor.Rock;
import info.gridworld.actor.Actor;
import info.gridworld.actor.Flower;
import info.gridworld.actor.Bug;
import info.gridworld.grid.Location;
import info.gridworld.grid.BoundedGrid;
import info.gridworld.actor.ActorWorld;

public class APlusCritterRunner
{
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    ActorWorld world = new ActorWorld(new BoundedGrid<Actor>(8,8));
    world.add(new Location(3, 1), new Rock());
    world.add(new Location(5, 2), new Actor());
    world.add(new Location(7, 6), new Flower());
    world.add(new Location(6, 6), new Actor());
    world.add(new Location(0, 5), new Actor());
    world.add(new Location(3, 5), new Actor());
    world.add(new Location(1, 1), new AnnoyingCritter());
    world.show(); 
}
}
```

tl;dr Grid returns null, not sure why.

Any input is appreciated, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
public class AnnoyingCritter extends Critter
{
    Random gen = new Random();
    Grid<Actor> world = null;
    Actor bFF = null;

    public Actor pickFriend() {
        world = getGrid();
        if (world == null)
            return;
        ArrayList<Location> locs = world.getOccupiedLocations();
        int pick = gen.nextInt(locs.size());
        Actor temp = world.get(locs.get(pick));
        while(temp instanceof Rock || temp instanceof Flower) {
            pick = gen.nextInt(locs.size());
            temp = world.get(locs.get(pick));
        }
        return temp;
    }

    public void figureDirection() {
        bFF = pickFriend();
        ...
        if(world.get(next) != null && (next != bFF.getLocation() || world.get(next) instanceof Rock)) {
            world.get(next).removeSelfFromGrid();
            moveTo(next);
        }
        ...
    }

    public void act() {
        figureDirection();
    }
```

I think that your problem is that you are declaring and initializing `world` before the
AnnoyingCritter is put into a grid. `world.add(new Location(1, 1), new
AnnoyingCritter());` first has to create a new Location and a new AnnoyingCritter *then*
add it to the grid. So when the AnnoyingCritter is first created it is not in a grid.

You also have to move your call to `pickFriends()` from your fields to the beginning of
`figureDirection()`. That way `world` can be initialized, and you will avoid another
NullPointerException.

There is also a `NullPointerException` when you say `world.get(next).removeSelfFromGrid();`
If `next` does not contain an Actor you cannot call `.removeSelfFromGrid().`